# Java―escape string to use in RegExp

Tags: java, regex

I am a bit new to Java, so I am just unsure if I am doing things like they should or not. I am developing a Program, that is more for learning Java purpose and which is thought for commandline use. One of the Features should be a kind of search an replace.

Starting the program from the commandline like this:

```
java -jar pro.jar -s ${ftp://www.stuff.com} -r foo
```

means: search for the exact String `${ftp://www.stuff.com}` and replace it with `foo`. I want to search with an Regexp, so I have to escape the escape-characters ($,(,{,},\,…) in the search string.

```
${ftp://www.stuff.com} --> \$\{ftp:\/\/www\.stuff\.com\}
```

Therefore I wrote that function:

```
private static Pattern getSearchPattern()
{
    String searchArg = cli.getOptionValue( "s" ).trim();
    StringBuffer escapedSearch = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern metas = Pattern.compile( "([\\.\\?\\*\\{\\}\\[\\]\\(\\)\\^\\$\\+\\|\\\\])" );
    Matcher metaMatcher = metas.matcher( searchArg );

    while( metaMatcher.find() )
    {
        metaMatcher.appendReplacement(escapedSearch, "\\\\\\\\$0" );
    }
    metaMatcher.appendTail( escapedSearch );

    return Pattern.compile( escapedSearch.toString() );
}
```

all in all does this work, but there are so many backslashes. Does this escape all metachrackters? Is that a »robust« solution?

Comment: dont know if its a possibility for you but maybe you could make sure there's just a single argument that accepts patterns and provide it always as the last one. then the remainder ofthe commandline is always your argument and there's less escaping to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something much better than use them. You can use a `PatternQuote`.

```
Pattern metas = Pattern.quote("no escaped regex chars in here");
```

One other way to get rid of `\\` is to use character classes `[]`. So if you put `[.]` instead of `\\.` the results will be the same and hopefully you get some readability.

Comment: +1 for `Pattern.quote`, which is designed for precisely this task. There's also `Matcher.quoteReplacement` which you can use on the replacement string if you want it to be treated literally (rather than `$1` being treated as a backreference to a capturing group in the pattern).

Comment: Thank you! Works just like expected! Nice!